# How to group time on Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have several time intervals, and I am looking for a trend. The data, however, is spaced in intervals that make it impossible to comprehend.

- How do I reduce the space of the time intervals to 1/2 hour? Hopefully quickly and easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DATETRUNC formula, ie:

```
datetrunc('hour',[datetime field])
```

You can probably nest it to break it down to 1/2 hour intervals.